# Limiting the number of results in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa

I have 20+ tables in my DB and I need to have a method to fetch all non-deleted rows from the tables. Therefore, I wrote the following interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CommonRepositry<T, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, UUID>{
    List<T> findByIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted);
}
```

All my model repositories extend this `CommonRepositry` and I'm able to access all the non-deleted rows:

```
public interface ModelNameRepository extends CommonRepositry<ModelName, UUID> { 
// sevral spring JPA methods
```

As the tables are growing in size, I want to put an *adjustable* limit on the number of results that the method returns. There are two ways to do so and I'm having issues with both of them:

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result), this is how I am supposed to do it:

```
List<User> findTop1000ByIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted);
```

It only returns me the top 1000 rows.

**PROBLEM:** I want to externalise this `1000` to the properties file so that if I have to change, I do it only at a single place.

Another way to do that would be to use `@Query` annotation and write the SQL query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table_name" + " WHERE is_deleted = :isDeleted LIMIT 1000;", nativeQuery = true)
List<T> findByIsDeleted(@Param("isDeleted")boolean isDeleted);
```

**PROBLEM:** how do I get the table_name? My model class names to table-names have simple CamelCase to camel_case mapping. But how do I get the model class name from `T`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You can pass a second parameter to your query, called Pageable.

`List<T> findByIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted, Pageable pageable);`

This `Pageable` is an interface, but you can use the `PageRequest` implementation for it. It requires two things to create a `PageRequest`, the page number and the size (meaning that how many rows you want to fetch). Of course, in your case the page number is 0 and the size should be set by reading the value from the properties file.

**Problem 2:** You can externalize the table name to a class which only consists of constant values. You can use these values in your `@Table` annotation on your entity class and here as well.

More reading: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 3.2.0-M1 you can also use a `Limit` instead of a `Pageable`.

```
List<User> findByIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted, Limit.of(1000));
```

Since `1000` is now just a simple value you can get it from a property file, make it a constant or get it from wherever you want.

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/3052 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2827, especially the documentation bits here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/a5408a478d015bb5e83de62c3872119b02ad89a7