# Dynamic limit in Spring Repository find Request

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, limit

I have a repository, where I select and process 100 customers every day.

This is done with:

```java
List<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findFirst100();
```

That is clear so far.
But the number of 100 needs to be configurable.
So I added the variable, which is read at every startup out of the config file:

```java
@Value("${customers.daily-limit:100}")
private Integer                            dailyLimit;
List<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findFirst100();
customer.stream().limit(dailyLimit).forEach(c -> {...})
```

The problem is, that in this way I am limited to the maximum of the `findFirst100` and can't exceed it. So I can use `findAll()`, but if I have over 100'000 customers in my repository, the performance would be very bad if I load all, just to take 200 instead of 100 out.
So, is there any way, I can limit the amount of customer it should load with the dynamic parameter?

Thank you for your answer.

Edit:
So you mean something like this?

```java
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, dailyLimit, Direction.ASC, "id");
Page<Customer> pagedResult = customerRepository.findAll(pageable);
List<Customer> customers = pagedResult.getContent();
```

Comment: Why not simply make the repository extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` (or `JpaRepository`) and use `findAll(Pageable page)`?

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect ;)
Sometimes you just need a hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting the number of results in Spring data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319241/limiting-the-number-of-results-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: With paging it works. I'll have always only one page but I can limit the amount of this page via the configuration.